# Why is wp_enqueue_scripts not working?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a simple call to the wp_enqueue_scripts hook but it won't run the function:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_gz_scripts' );
function add_gz_scripts() {
    wp_register_script('hdgzjs',plugins_url('/js/hdgz.js', __FILE__),'','',true);
    wp_enqueue_script('hdgzjs');
}
```

I'm not getting a "file not found" on the js file and I'm not getting in php errors. It's just not running the function. I've tried echoing inside the function to test and it won't even echo. Aside from this the plugin activates and runs fine.

Comment: Glad to know that and I'm deleting the answer and you just put your own answer as you described in the comment for future reference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For anyone who comes across this:

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', '...' ); is for site side
add_action( 'admin_init', '...' ); is for admin side

When you stare at code too long it's easy to overlook doing this.